# Underscore bind not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, underscore.js

I'm using _.bind from underscore.js, however it is not working within IE8/9.

I understand MDN has a work around ([MDN Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) - but not sure if this can be applied to the underscore library, or whether there is a fix for this in underscore itself

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
window.onload = _.bind(function() { 

     this.product.quantityListing();
}, this);
```

EDIT: I'm using an instance of _.bind else where and it works in IE8 - however it is just not working when I want to check the window has loaded in IE.

Comment: Why are you using `new _.bind(fn)` here? The `new` seems useless here.

Comment: Underscore basically **is** a collection of polyfills.

Comment: Yeah that's the route I've gone down, but I just wanted to avoid doing that and making use of _.bind - however need to move on so will have to suffice

Answer (score 3):

`_.bind` and the `Function#bind` shim from MDN do essentially the same thing. If you use the MDN method, you need not use the Underscore.js method.

You would use the MDN method like this:

```
window.onload = (function() {
    this.product.quantityListing();
}).bind(this);
```

On the other hand, if you use the MDN shim before you include  Underscore in your page, Underscore will use the shimmed version if necessary.

So if you include the shim before Underscore, you can use whichever you prefer. Personally I'd stick with using `Function#bind`, because it has (very slightly) better performance in browsers that natively support it.

Comment: Worth noting underscore will use Function.bind if present so if the MDN shim is loaded before underscore then underscore will use that shim as it will create Function.bind. Useful if the code base is already using it and a refactor is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The whole premise of Underscore is that it *does* work for IE8 as well as other browsers, but the way in which you're using it is highly unusual if not plain wrong. You would use it like so:

```
window.onload = _.bind(function() {
    this.product.quantityListing();
}, this);
```

*I.e. without the `new` keyword.*

The result of `_.bind()` is a closure onto which `this` is bound; once the document is done loading it will call the function with the expected context.

Comment: that was my bad, the new isn't suppose to be there - however it still doesn't work